# Transverse speed of hamster in wheel as function of theta

Tags: torque, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

i need help with conceptual understanding of how this system works.

A small animal is running in a wheel with radius R, (and 0 mass). When the animal is at an angle $\theta = \alpha $ measured from the vertical direction to $\vec r$ of the animal, it's speed relative the room is 0.

I have problems understanding all these kind of systems. The speed as a function of $\theta $ is:
$-gsin\theta = a$
$gRcos\theta =v²/2+c$

$mv²/2 = mgRcos\theta -mgRcos\alpha$
$ v = \pm \sqrt{2gR(cos\theta -cos\alpha )}$

I know the answer is correct, but I don't think I have used the right approach as it feels very unintuitive, can anyone please help me understand how this system works?